does nextjs render the child components on client if parent component is rendered on client
When I'm creating a custom authentication using firebase. I added the auth flow in one component(AuthComp) and had to use "use client" to make it work. Now if I add any component/page render as a child of this AuthComp will it be rendered server side or client side?
I tried finding answers but everywhere it says the answer is "client side" but if I look at the network tab the page seems to have generated server side.enter image description here
